# Continuous Deployment of VSTS app with Git submodules fails on Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, git-submodules, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy a VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) Git app including submodules to Azure using the `Deployment source` option in the Azure web app.

All submodules are hosted in the same VSTS project but under different Git repositories.

The deployment to Azure fails with the following error message:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com': Bad
>   file descriptor\nClone of
>   'https://XXX.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/Project/_git/Project.API.Models'
>   into submodule path 'lib/api-models' failed\n\r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe submodule update --init --recursive

Is there any way to deploy Git projects including submodules to Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out a workaround on how to make git deployments on Azure work with submodules.

1. Create a personal access token by clicking on clone in VSTS and then personal access token.
2. Copy the access token and modify the URL of all submodules in the `.gitmodules` files.
3. The url of the git modules should look like this afterwards: `https://deployment:YOURCOPIEDAPIKEY@XXX.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/Project/_git/Project.API.Models`

Make sure you paste the API key in all submodules and submodules of submodules. Commit and push and you are good to go.
The username `deployment` in this case can be any random name.